# Find variance of a Normal Distribution

Tags: probability, normal-distribution

If $\theta\sim N(0,\sigma)$, I want to know the value of $\sigma$ such that $P(-69<\theta<69)=0.99$
I tried from different values but I want to know if there is a specific way to find it.

Comment: For which $z$ is $P(-z\sigma<\theta<z\sigma)=0.99$? (Don't just say $69/\sigma$.)